# The covariance between 2 linear equations

Tags: regression

There are 2 dependent variables y1 & y2 and they are regressed on same independent variable x, i.e.

y1 = 0.9x + epsilon_t1
y2 = 1.1x + epsilon_t2

If var(x) = 0.2 and var(epsilon) = 0.1, what is the solution for the covariance(y1,y2)? Thanks.

Comment: can you share what you've done so far?